# Reloading a scene through a coroutine changes textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have set up a die coroutine so I can delay the death. When it reloads the scene all of the textures go from diffuse white to a diffuse brown.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjVIF.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcxBl.png)

```
    IEnumerator Die()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

Comment: Please fix the links to your images. We can't see them

Comment: look fine to me

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjVIF.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcxBl.png

Comment: Mind leaving​ g a link? Jesus Christ you really gave me the third degree didnt you

Comment: alright whelp would you mind un doing what ever you did to mark it as duplicate because i don't even have the option in to turn off auto generate lightmaps.

Comment: i am using unity 5.5.1 and the article said that this option was for 5.4 and above...